# Why doesn't my NavDrawer open when clicking my navigation icon?

Tags: android, toolbar

I use a custom navigation icon so I need to `drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`. But now, my Navdrawer does not open when clicking my custom icon.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Do I even still need an ActionBarDrawerToggle?

```
public void setUpActionBar() {
    actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.custom_screen_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(actionBar);

    actionBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.divider_action_bar);
    actionBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.action_bar_menu);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    actionBar, /* custom action bar */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

I also tried using the `drawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon);` so that I could change te icon without using the `setNavigationIcon` from action bar, but it does not change the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the `drawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon);` and `drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` then it will run

```
public void setHomeAsUpIndicator(Drawable indicator) {
        if(indicator == null) {
            this.mHomeAsUpIndicator = this.getThemeUpIndicator();
            this.mHasCustomUpIndicator = false;
        } else {
            this.mHomeAsUpIndicator = indicator;
            this.mHasCustomUpIndicator = true;
        }

        if(!this.mDrawerIndicatorEnabled) {
            this.setActionBarUpIndicator(this.mHomeAsUpIndicator, 0);
        }
```

and

```
public void setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean enable) {
        if(enable != this.mDrawerIndicatorEnabled) {//if you set enable be "false", below sentences do not run, because the default value of mDrawerIndicatorEnabled is false 
            if(enable) {
                this.setActionBarUpIndicator((Drawable)this.mSlider, this.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(8388611)?this.mCloseDrawerContentDescRes:this.mOpenDrawerContentDescRes);
            } else {
                this.setActionBarUpIndicator(this.mHomeAsUpIndicator, 0);
            }

            this.mDrawerIndicatorEnabled = enable;
        }

    }
```

although you call the setHomeAsUpIndicator(Drawable indicator), because mDrawerIndicatorEnabled is false, therefore it doesn't change the icon.(But if you call `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled` first and then call `setHomeAsUpIndicator` you can change the icon as well).

If you call `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);`, the icon will change, because it will call the `setActionBarUpIndicator` in `ActionBarDrawerToggle.java`. You will see the toolbar will set this drawable for its navigation icon.

```
public void setActionBarUpIndicator(Drawable upDrawable, int contentDescRes) {
            this.mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(upDrawable);
            this.mToolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(contentDescRes);
        }
```

If you want to open the drawer menu with your click, you should set a click listener for this 'navigationIcon', because after you calling this, system will not help you for this.

Answer (score 0):

`setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` will disable the drawer indicator so my guess is that it needs to be set as true. Also if you need a custom icon for the drawer you can set it as,

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.earth,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                )
```

The drawable argument should replace the up caret.

Useful [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#) with an sample download.

Comment: I am using `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;` will your solution still be viable?

Comment: It says it is undefined. The constructor is undefined

Comment: Let me try this with the support lib!

Comment: This will not work with support v7 , since it requires a toolbar